# why escape sequence can't be represented as unicodeEscape in java?

Tags: java, ansi-escape

In java,

"Carriage return" is represented as `'\r'`

&

"Line Feed" is represented as `'\n'`.

But Java does not allow,

"Carriage return" as `'\u000d'`

and

"Line Feed"  as `'\u000a'`.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode escape sequences are applied earlier in the source transformation than the character literal escape sequences. Unicode escape sequences are transformed *very* early in the process - before any other lexing happens, including before line breaks are detected. See [JLS 3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) for details.

So when you put `\u000a` into a Java source file, it will behave exactly as if you'd put an *actual* line feed in there - causing a line break as far as the rest of the compiler is concerned.

(Personally I think this was a design mistake; I prefer the C# approach of only allowing Unicode escape sequences at very specific points in the code, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Remember Java allows a very wide variety of characters in identifiers. I believe the intent was to allow people with limited (e.g. ASCII) text editors to include those characters outside string literals. That said, a rule that such literals are not replaced between double quotes or apostrophe (i.e. in string or character literals) until parsing the literal is practical and would have served both purposes.

Comment: @DanAllen: C# allows escape sequences within identifiers, and even has an `@` prefix to allow keywords to be used as identifiers. Basically it's feasible to make it broader than just character literals without making it apply *everywhere*.

Comment: I agree. I was pointing out how I believe Java got to where it is. I'm going with "missed opportunity" rather than "design mistake". But the distinction is very fine and certainly not worth arguing.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode escapes are recognised anywhere in a Java source file, not just inside string literals, and are processed very early in the compiler chain. A `\u000d` is treated as a literal carriage return, not an escaped one, i.e. For the source code

```
String cr = "\u000d";
```

what the compiler sees is

```
String cr = "
";
```

And this is not legal Java code.

Comment: but why compiler is interpreting the way it is within double quotes. content within string literals is not for parsing the file, but for lexical reasons.

Comment: [Dan Allen's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750637/why-escape-sequence-cant-be-represented-as-unicodeescape-in-java/30750790#comment49556249_30750786) on the other answer explains it nicely - Java allows a wide range of Unicode characters in identifiers so the early processing of `\uNNNN` escapes provides a way to represent source code that includes non-ASCII characters in a way that is robust in situations which may not be Unicode-safe (e.g. a Mac user and a Windows user sharing source code but with different default encodings on their text editors).